# Is praying without ghusl kufr?

Tags: women, ghusl, salat-al-qasr, depression, prophet-dawud

Sometimes after having a wet dream for example, I just cannot bring myself to do ghusl. I feel incredibly guilty and I’m also scared of punishment, but I have depression and anxiety which just makes showering seem so difficult. I am not saying that it’s justified if I don’t do ghusl, but i struggle with it. It’s kind of become a fear for me to even fall asleep bc I’m scared I might have a wet dream. Am I a kaafir?

Answer (score 0):

The prayer without Ghusl is completely invalid and it's a sin on its own to pray without Ghusl, though not Kufr.

You can literally sleep and not pray Fajr at all than pray It without Ghusl, both are the same thing, If not the second one's worse.

A number of scholars even conclude that praying without Ghusl is Kufr as It is a supposed act of disrespecting Salat.

Comment: It should be added that some scholars may consider it to be kufr as it may be mocking the act of worship.

Comment: Thanks. I feel so so guilty and scared when that happens but showering is just genuinely so difficult to me I really don’t know what to do. I don’t wanna be a kaafir

Comment: @user2007 "It should be added that some scholars may consider it to be kufr as it may be mocking the act of worship."

Agreed, adding it right now.

Comment: @asdfgh Try to do the Ghusl and If you cannot then definitely most certainly don't pray, instead pray the Qada prayer and ask for repentance. But the best act for you to do is actually push yourself to do Ghusl.

Allah expresses happiness to his Angels and his Angels pray for the person with happiness when someone even wakes up on Fajr to pray with his eyes filled with sleepiness.

So just imagine how much Allah will reward you If you fight yourself and the temperature doing the Ghusl properly.

May Allah make it easy on you.

Comment: Thank you,I will try